# disable single button in react after map

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I am creating a lottery picker and i want to disable the button after selected.

I have mapped through the numbers to create the button, i am checking in the map if the number has been picked already and setting the disable to true if it has

however it does seem to work

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  let [lottopick, setlottopick] = useState([]);
  // const [disabled, setdisabled] = useState(false);
  const nums = [...Array(50).keys()].splice(1);

  const lottopickfunc = (e) => {
    if (lottopick.length < 6) {
      
      setlottopick((curr) => {
        return [...curr, e.target.textContent];
      });
    } else if (lottopick.length === 6) {
      // setdisabled(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="grid">
        {nums.map((num) => {
          return (
            <button
              className="grid-item"
              disabled={lottopick.includes(num) ? true : false}
              key={num}
              onClick={lottopickfunc}
            >
              {num}
            </button>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

`nums` is an array of numbers, while `typeof  e.target.textContent == "string"`.

`[1, 2, 3].includes("2")` will always be false.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your `lottopick` array contains strings because you're just reading `e.target.textContent` and then when you compare them with the values in the `nums` array which contains actual numbers, it never satisfies the `disabled` condition. For example when I pick number `24`, you add `'24'` to `lottopick` and then the `disabled` logic becomes `['24'].includes(24)` which is falsey. So the fix would be to just put actual numbers in `lottopick`. So `Number(e.target.textContent)` as opposed to `e.target.textContent`.